# Can I expand the coefficients of these two (multivariate) polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I do have two multivariate polynomials that I want to set to equality to extract some parameters. For that, I want to equate the coefficients of these polynomials, but they are not given in standard expanded form. It looks like it could be done by hand, but I have trouble doing it myself.

Define the two polynomials $P$ and $Q$, define for a given $x \in \mathbb C^{d}$ by :

$$P(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i \left[\prod\limits_{j=1,\;j\neq i}^{n} \left(1 - \langle r_j, x \rangle\right)\right]$$

$$Q(x) = \left(\sum\limits_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le m} f_\alpha x^{\alpha}\right)\left[\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n} \left(1 - \langle r_j, x \rangle\right)\right]$$

Where I denoted :

- The variable $x$ belongs to $\mathbb C^d$
- $\alpha$ are multiindexes in $\mathbb N^d$
- $x^\alpha = \prod\limits_{i=1}^d x_i^{\alpha_i}$
- $\langle .,.\rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product between two vectors
- The sum in $Q$ is taken over all mutliindexes that have the sum of their components smaller than $m$

The parameters of the problem are :

- $m,n,d$ are three integers defining the dimension of the problem.
- $a_1,...,a_n$ are real valued parameters
- $r_1,...,r_n$ are all $d$-dimensional parameters
- $f_\alpha$ are real valued parameters

Question: For all $\beta \in \mathbb N^d$, how can I express $p_\beta$ and $q_\beta$ such that :

$$P(x) = \sum\limits_{\beta\in \mathbb N} p_\beta x^\beta \text{ and }Q(x) = \sum\limits_{\beta \in \mathbb N} q_\beta x^\beta$$.

It should be doable, but I have trouble finding the general form of $p_\beta$ and $q_\beta$ (i.e expanding the two polynomials).

Comment: When $m=0$, $Q$ is an arbitrary product of linear polynomials (with constant term 1). Do you have an answer for this special case?

Comment: Thanks to your momment, i managed to perform the extension.. before i realised that this was not at all the thing i wanted to solve hahaha. Thanks anyway